# Can I connect these two different types of drain material together? If so, what sealant should I use?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, bathtub

I'm preparing to replace a bathtub and the new one requires a different drain assembly (the overfill drain is a wide-mouth connector).

Anyway, I'm noticing that the new drain pipe material itself is different - a white plastic (PVC?) compared to the old drain which is a black plastic (not sure what it is).

[image: Old drain on the left, new on the right]

Is it OK to mix these two types of materials? I seem to recall that some plastics can't be interconnected together or that a special glue is required.

If it IS OK, what type of sealant should I get? Just a standard silicone glue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Black plastic drain pipes are typically ABS. White, usually PVC. There is a special cement that can join the two which will be found in the area with regular PVC cement at the plumbing supply. Just check the label carefully.

Not silicone - no way, no how, don't go there.

Comment: The glue for this is often labeled "universal", or "multi-purpose".